# how to access to specific value from element Row

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

in angular material table we need to make structure of data like this : 
***{personne: Ali, applicationX: 10, applicationY: 20 , ApplicationZ: 30}*** 
but in my case i have data like : 
***{ "Ali": [ { "nameofApp": "applicationX", "valueOfApp": 10 }, { "nameofApp": "applicationY", "valueOfApp": 20 }, { "nameofApp": "applicationZ", "valueOfApp": 30 } ] }*** 
in td tag : <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> element | json }} 

the result showing the entire line : 
[image]

in my case i want to show specific value its

```
valueOfApp from ApplicaitonY (20)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "easy response" is

```
element.ali[1].valueOfApp
```

But I think you should transform your data.

First you get all the differents "applications" based in your data

You can use reduce and filter to remove the duplicate elements

```
 apps=Object.keys(this.data).reduce((a,b)=>
        [...a,...this.data[b].map(a=>a.nameofApp)],[])
        .filter((x,index,arr)=>arr.indexOf(x)==index)
```

Or using new Set

```
apps=Object.keys(this.data).reduce((a,b)=>
     [...new Set([...a,...this.data[b].map(a=>a.nameofApp)])],[])
```

Then you transform your data in the way

```
  dataTransform=Object.keys(this.data).map(key=>{
    const obj={personne:key}
    this.apps.forEach(a=>{
      console.log(this.data[key])
      const app=this.data[key].find(x=>x.nameofApp==a)
      obj[a]=app?app.valueOfApp:0
    })
    return obj
  })
```

So you has an array of elements with the properties: "personne" and the differents appsNames

See a [little stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s4gb2m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) (I create the variables when I defined, in general you need declare and, in the function you get the data give value to them)

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work for me!!
he said :  Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: data[b].map is not a function or its return value is not iterable
TypeError: data[b].map is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Comment: in you e.g. this.data[b] should be `data.Ali` that it's an array. When we have an object, Object.keys(your-object) is an array with the "properties" of the your-object. replace the "reduce" by some like `apps=Object.keys(this.data).reduce((a,b)=>{console.log(b)return [...a,...this.data[b].map(a=>a.nameofApp)]},]).filter((x,index,arr)=>arr.indexOf(x)==index)` and see what is happened :(

Comment: thank you for Help! but the last thing I did was convert data with <br> let result= this.myDataSource.reduce((h, obj)=>Object.assign(h,{ [obj.Personne]:( h[obj.Personne] || [] ).concat(obj.apps) }),{})
    for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(result)){
      this.DT.push({Personne: key, apps: value});}
      console.log(this.DT);
output :
Personne: "Ali"
apps: Array(3)
0: {ApplicarionX: 10}
1: {ApplicarionY: 20}
2: {ApplicarionZ: 30}
but when i use it in html file i need to loop into apps :8
i need to make apps like this :
{ApplicaitonX : 10 , ApplciaitonY:20 , ApplocaiotnZ:30}